# ImportError: cannot import name 'KeyTextTransform' from 'django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb'

Tags: django, django-3.2, django-4.1

What is the new import for:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'KeyTextTransform' from 'django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb'
```

I did some internet searching and didn't find an immediate result for the error.

I am trying to upgrade from django 3.2 to django 4.1.2

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the field type was migrated to the following location:

```
django.db.models.fields.json.KeyTextTransform
```

So for django4+:

```
from django.db.models.fields.json import KeyTextTransform
```

Instead of:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import KeyTextTransform
```